# Steam login with Vue js applicaiton

Tags: vue.js, passport.js, steam, steam-web-api, passport-jwt

I'm writing in here because i want to make an application which handles counter-strike tournaments.

I want to develop this app in VueJS, nodeJS and mongoDB. Is there a way i can login to steam and fetch account information for the user via vue js? I've searched everywhere but couldnt fint any documentation for this. I've made it work on my nodeJS api but when it comes to sessions and authentication does it only work on my api url which is not the same as my vue js application.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Steam has an [OpenID API](https://steamcommunity.com/dev) provider.  Have you looked into that?

Comment: Yes but i could not figure out an way to login via this from my vue application

Comment: @zero298 there is a npm for steam-passport and i can get it working in nodejs but dont know the aprroach in vueis

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any Vue but here is some HTML instead. This achieves the login as outlined in the official [Steam documentation](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/auth#website).

```html
    <form action="https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="openid.identity"
               value="http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select" />
        <input type="hidden" name="openid.claimed_id"
               value="http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select" />
        <input type="hidden" name="openid.ns" value="http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="openid.mode" value="checkid_setup" />
        <input type="hidden" name="openid.realm" value="https:\\yourOpenIdRealm.com" />
        <input type="hidden" name="openid.return_to" value="https:\\YourDomainUrlToReturnTo.com" />
        <Button type="submit">Log in through Steam</Button>
    </form>
```

> Is there a way i can login to steam and fetch account information for the user via vue js?

- The user will click the button in this form on your site and will be redireced to the Steam community login page.
- The user can then log into their Steam account on the Steam community pages.
- With `YourDomainUrlToReturnTo` you specify where the user retuns to your site after successful login via Steam.
- Steam will provide the Steam ID in the browser's [location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).
- With that Steam ID you can fetch user info via the [Steam Web API](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi_overview).

Comment: Hey, did you manage to resolve this at all? Its proving really difficult for me.