# Adding Steam-Login to VueJS SPA

Tags: laravel, vue.js, openid

I'm trying to get Steam login to work with my SPA (Vuejs+Laravel).

Ive thought about using a Socialite package for [Steam](https://packagist.org/packages/socialiteproviders/steam) and then [vue-social-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-social-auth)

However, it looks like that `vue-social-auth` wont work with any OpenID protocol, but only with `OAuth`.
Whenever I try to login, I'm getting an error called `Invalid OAuth Type`.

Is there another option to login with Steam using a SPA?

Comment: the question has [already been asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59649334/steam-login-with-vue-js-applicaiton). I hope you get help with it.

Comment: I know the idea behind it, but sending for example a JWT back to the clientside is the actual issue. This video shows how I need it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifhiVVVtLSw

When a user clicks the button and then logs in, I redirect them to ```/auth/callback```, there the user gets inserted if he doesnt exist and then redirect him back to ```/``` - however, when I already redirect him with ```return```, how would I pass the json with the JWT token?